# Am I missing something about the use of PHP's PDO?

Tags: php, database, pdo

Here's a simple piece of code I'm writing:

```
class LessonsLearntServiceTyped
{
    private $username = "***********";
    private $password = "***********";
    private $dsn      = "mysql:dbname=lessonslearnt;host=****
******.db.******.hostedresource.com";
    private $dbh;


    public function __construct(){
        try{
            $dbh = new PDO($this->dsn, $this->username, $this->password);

        }catch(PDOException $e){
            echo "Connection failed: ".$e->getMessage();
        }
    }



     public function returnAllEntries(){
        $query = "select * from lessons_learnt order by id";

    }

}
```

OK. I've not had much experience with PDO before but I've seen some examples on the net and apparently you can't serialize or de-serialize a PDO object.(that's the error message I get when I try to set a PDO object to an instance variable so that I can use it later)

Well, if we can't have PDO objects as instance variables, how then will I proceed on to writing the `returnAllEntries()` method? Will I have to create the PDO object again so I can use it there??(and also a new PDO object for *each* function I write that deals with the database)?

**What am I missing here?**

Thank you all in advance

**EDIT**

`$this->dbh = new PDO($this->dsn, $this->username, $this->password);` is what I wanted to do.

**But** when I do that I get the following error message:**note** this error message comes *from the PHPUnit console* which I'm using to tunit-test this class. In the browser it doesn't show any errors.

""You cannot serialize or unserialize PDO instances"

Comment: Why would you need to serialize it anyway?

Comment: See, if I have multiple functions and each one of them does a different thing in the database, I would like to be able to **only use one PDO object** for all of them, and the only way I can see of doing that would be setting the PDO object to an instance variable, so I could alway access it by writing `$this->dbh` or something similar.

Comment: So wait, were you just trying to assign your PDO object to `$this->dbh`, or were you actually calling `serialize()`?

Comment: Exactly! I thought it was clear from my snippet. I'm only trying to assign the PDO object to an instance variable! But the error message I get is that "it's not possible to serialize a PDO object"

Comment: The actual error message will show a different line for the error source. http://fabien.potencier.org/article/9/php-serialization-stack-traces-and-exceptions

Comment: Actually, the error is given by the PHPUnit console thing. When I open it up on the browser no errors come up. How come?

Comment: Does my last post change anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem was with my instance of PHPUnit test runner.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this is a very very weird edge case with exceptions from reading this:

http://fabien.potencier.org/article/9/php-serialization-stack-traces-and-exceptions

Try taking out the `$e->getMessage()` line bit in your catch statement and see if it changes anything.